# The 'sequenceNumber' header value must be an Integer. But it is Long

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

I'm using the RabbitMQ 3.6.10 UI to publish a message that is received by my Java application that uses Spring Integration AMQP 4.3.11. The message is a reply to an earlier message that was created using a Splitter, so it had a `sequenceNumber` and `sequenceSize` headers. I copy these headers to the reply and set them to the type `Number` in the RabbitMQ UI. However, on the Java side, I'm getting an exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Message conversion failed
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'sequenceNumber' header value must be an Integer.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92)
    at org.springframework.integration.IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.verifyType(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor.setHeader(MessageHeaderAccessor.java:298)
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor.copyHeaders(MessageHeaderAccessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.copyHeaders(MessageBuilder.java:177)
    at org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder.copyHeaders(MessageBuilder.java:47)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.processMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:203)
    ... 14 more
```

I checked that the types of the `sequenceNumber` and `sequenceSize` headers on the Java side are `Long`, instead of `Integer`. There is however no option to make this difference in the RabbitMQ UI. The messages will be sent by a non-Java application, so how do I make sure the headers get recognised as Integer by Spring Integration?

When I publish the reply using a Java client and set the header values to `Integer`, then the consumer accepts them. So this is probably a limitation of the RabbitMQ UI not having the header types specific enough (eg. 32-bit vs. 64-bit number) or Java client being too strict about the expected value type. Can anyone confirm one or the other?

Comment: What do you mean by "set them to type" if you say that you just propagate them? Are you testing something manually, e.g. the reply case?

Comment: @ArtemBilan - yes, I'm testing the reply case manually via the RabbitMQ UI. There the only possible header types are: String, Number, Boolean, List. By "propagate" I meant here "copying the value manually".

Comment: I think we should be more lenient; see my answer for a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `MessagePostProcessor` to the adapter's listener container...

```
@Bean
public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter(ConnectionFactory cf) {
    AmqpInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer(cf));
    adapter.setOutputChannelName("someChannel");
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public AbstractMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer(ConnectionFactory cf) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
    container.setQueueNames("foo");
    container.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(m -> {
        if (m.getMessageProperties().getHeaders()
                .get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER) instanceof Long) {
            Integer sequenceNumber = ((Long) m.getMessageProperties().getHeaders()
                    .get(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER)).intValue();
            m.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().put(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER,
                    sequenceNumber);
        }
        return m;
    });
    return container;
}
```

Please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) - we should probably be more lenient, especially if the value is < `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Yes, you can do the same using `HeaderEnricher` before `Aggregator`. I mean remap `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.SEQUENCE_NUMBER` to itself but using `.intValue()` and `overwrite=true` option.

Comment: @Artem - the failure is in the channel adapter `at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:223)`

Comment: Doh... Indeed `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.verifyType()` is restricted to only `Integer` on the matter. Not my day today... Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. I created [INT-4349](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4349). For now I'll use a simple Java publisher for testing - this one sets the header types in a compatible way.